# Spring Rest Data Application in Google Appengine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

I've a Spring rest service Application with spring Data Repositories,which I want to deploy to Google APP engine.

But when i try to activate the Google AppEngine settings in my Project properties it comes to an error as soon as i enter a value for Applications ID.  cannot set application ID(appengine-web.XML)

I want to put a appegine-web.XML into WEB-INF folder, but WEB-INF folder does not exist in my project.

Comment: You're going to have to add way more info to get help.  For example, where exactly are you changing these Project properties?  You say you don't have a WEB-INF folder, is this not a J2EE web app?

Comment: I use Spring toolsuite 3.6.3 and i guess i use the springs internal Webserver for the restservice and i dont know how to change the Server enviroment for my project....

Comment: Did you look at this? https://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/920/springsource-tool-suite-google-app-engine

Comment: have you added the Google plugin for eclipse?

Comment: @jirungaray- Yes i've the Google Plugin installed

Comment: @Robert thanks your link takes me one step further. I've now created a war/WEB-INF folder and put my appengine-web.XML there. Now i can enter the missing ApplicationID. I'm now able to Start the Applications AS a webapp in Google appengine environments, but UT dies not sart my restfull spring service..... But i actually dont need the webap ...i only need the restfull service...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you are deploying a RESTFUL web service via spring at bottom this must look like a web application.  Isn't a WAR file the unit of deployment for the google app engine?